# change format of column

Tags: awk, sed, text-formatting

I have in the input file a column with the following format

```
H6
H7
O4
C4
H8
H9
O5
C5
H10
H11
```

I want the output to have the following format

```
"a H6"
"a H7"
"a O4"
"a C4"
"a H8"
"a H9"
"a O5"
"a C5"
"a H10"
"a H11"
```

I tried so far `awk '{print "a "$1""}' filein > fileout`

but the output was not the desired as I got a column with missing the `" "`.

Comment: please read https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers and please do on your all posts you asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must escape the double quotes in awk. Something like will do the work

```
awk '{print "\"a "$1 "\" "}' filein > fileout
```

Answer (score 1):

And use `printf` instead of `print` in your Awk command to output into a single line.

```
awk '{printf "\"a "$1"\" "}' inputFile > outputFile
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just use `sed` for this:

```
sed 's/^/"a /; s/$/"/' infile > outfile
```

This produces:

```
$ sed 's/^/"a /; s/$/"/' infile 
"a H6"
"a H7"
"a O4"
"a C4"
"a H8"
"a H9"
"a O5"
"a C5"
"a H10"
"a H11"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/.*/"a &"/' data
```

`&` is the whole matched text.